# Re-size the Text and Button/Label in Livecode

Tags: height, width, livecode, text-size

I have a livecode project with a button and a label. I want the width and height of the button and label changes when I re-size the window(stack). Also, I want the font size of the text in the label and button to change. I want to center the horizontal and vertical alignment of the text as the font size changes. I tried this code but the text exceeds the height of button/label (in bigger window size).

```
set the width of field "label" to the width of this stack * 0.8
set the height of field "label" to the height of this stack * 0.2
set the textsize of field "label" to the height of field "label" - 10
set the textheight of field "label" to the height of field "label"
```

This is what I'm expecting...

[image: Size of button and text in different window sizes.]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of smoothly resizing text as you resize the stack window is a tricky one. Here is a solution that may not be perfect, but it gets you close. The field has dontWrap set to true and margins set to 2. I also set an initial textFont and textSize for the field, so it's not just using an inherited textFont.

This handler is in the script of the card the field is on.

```
on resizeStack pNewWidth, pNewHeight
    set the width of field "label" to pNewWidth * 0.8
    set the height of field "label" to pNewHeight * 0.2
    set the topLeft of fld "label" to pNewWidth * 0.1, pNewHeight * 0.1
    lock screen
    if the formattedWidth of fld "label" > the width of fld "label" OR \
          the formattedHeight of fld "label" > the height of fld "label" then
        set the textSize of field "label" to the textSize of fld "label" - 1
    else if the formattedWidth of fld "label" < the width of fld "label" OR \
          the formattedHeight of fld "label" < the height of fld "label" then
        set the textSize of field "label" to the textSize of fld "label" + 1
    end if
    unlock screen
end resizeStack
```

Comment: It looks like the text is vibrating when I re-size the window that is sometimes annoying.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant when I said this method is "not perfect". You could explore the measureText() function and possibly the scaleFactor property of stacks for more ideas.

Comment: I found this script ` measureText(<text>, <object>, [ <mode> ])` how to use  this?